# Running Jackrabbit Garbage Collector on resource adapter

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

I want to run the datastore garbage collector with the resource adapter deployment model. I tried shutting down the jackrabbit-jca repository and then running the code proposed [here](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/DataStore#Running_Data_Store_Garbage_Collection_.28Jackrabbit_2.x.29) but I don't know which libraries I need to include, since I access jackrabbit only through the jcr api right now. I always get ClassDefNotFoundExceptions or java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violations. Jackrabbit version is 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of jar files required to run Jackrabbit, you could use Maven and list dependencies in the same way as [the project `jackrabbit-webapp` does](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/jackrabbit/trunk/jackrabbit-webapp/pom.xml?view=markup):

```
<properties>
    <jackrabbit.version>2.5.3</jackrabbit.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackrabbit-core</artifactId>
  <version>${jackrabbit.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr-server</artifactId>
  <version>${jackrabbit.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>${jackrabbit.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackrabbit-jcr-rmi</artifactId>
  <version>${jackrabbit.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you are not using Maven you could get the list of jar files by [downloading the jackrabbit-webapp](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/downloads.html) `jackrabbit-webapp-2.5.3.war`, then rename to `.zip`, and expand. The jar files are then in the directory `WEB-INF/lib`. That's the 'worst case' list, in reality you might not need things like pdfbox, poi, derby, and so on.